# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.TokenResponse deserialization error "Encountered unexpected character '<'"

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using the sample code from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi. When I receive an authorization code the method `ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` in the callback method `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` throws the exception:

`System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.OAuth2.TokenResponse. Encountered unexpected character '<'.`

Here's a snippet of the sample code:

```
/*
 * Callback function when an authorization code is received 
 */
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
{
    // Extract the code from the response notification
    var code = notification.Code;

    string signedInUserID = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, notification.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
    ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(ClientId, Authority, RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);
    try
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, Scopes);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO: Handle
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that the `Authority` URL that was being passed to `ConfidentialClientApplication`was invalid and was returning a HTTP 404 not found error. The `Authority` URL is created using the `Tenant` and `DefaultPolicy` values. In my case the `Tenant` and `DefaultPolicy` properties were being initialized after the `Authority` property resulting in the URL to not contain the proper values.

```
public static string Authority = String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy);
...
public static string Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
public static string DefaultPolicy = SignUpSignInPolicyId;
```

This resulted in the `Authority` URL to have the value:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp///v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

vs

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/my_tenant.onmicrosoft.com/my_policy/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

During my initial search I found this issue reported to
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/720 but no solution. I've posted my answer there to help anyone in the future.